# How do I change the default colors of a running Xterm?

Tags: colors, reset, xterm

When you start an xterm, its default colors are determined by .Xdefaults OR --fg and --bg options. Those are the defaults for this particular xterm process. If you then change colors with ansi sequences, when you send the ansi reset sequence, you get back to the colors it started up with.

What I want to change is **the defaults for this particular xterm process**. I want to, in effect, re-exec the xterm command with a new set of --fg and --bg options.

Is there an option to reset the **default** colors, not the current colors?

Answer (score 0):

The *dynamic colors* feature does that (does not get "reset" in the normal escape sequences, which use "ANSI" escapes):

> The 10 colors (below) which may be set or queried using 1 0
> through 1 9  are denoted *dynamic colors*, since the
> corresponding control sequences were the first means for
> setting xterm's colors dynamically, i.e., after it was
> started.  They are not the same as the ANSI colors (however,
> the dynamic text foreground and background colors are used
> when ANSI colors are reset using SGR 3 9  and 4 9 ,
> respectively).

- [Change VT100 text background color](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-0.1015) (**`OSC`** `11`)
- [Change VT100 text foreground color](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-0.1015) (**`OSC`** `10`)

Comment: Hmm. Looking at my code, I appear to be using OSC 10 and 11 to query the current colors... AH! I am doing that by executing an echo of those characters to /dev/null to get the current settings. If I don't divert to /dev/null then I should be able to SET those colors and not have an ansi reset affect them. I'll try and report back...